# How to make @DbLookup in XPages verify the existence of a value in another database?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have an XPage that is doing an @DbLookup with a user's input and trying to find that value in a view in a different database yet on the same server.

I have already verified that the view is in fact sorted by the first column and therefore @DbLookup friendly.  The following code below appears in the  server-side Javascript `OnClick` event handler for a button on my XPage.

My problem is that the an error occurs when trying to assign the value of lRep to the 'firstNameLabel'.  lRep is returning a null value from the dbLookup even though the a record under the 'FirstName' field exists with the key 'P301993'.  This dbLookup should be finding a returning a single 'FirstName' result.  However, it is not.

```
var resultLabel = getComponent("firstNameLabel");
var dbName = new Array(@DbName()[0],"UKCSandbox.nsf");
var lRep = @DbLookup(dbName,"customerLookup","P301993","FirstName");
resultLabel.setValue(lRep.toString());
```

Comment: I think the code should like `lRep = (typeof lRep == "string") ? "No result" : lRep;`. Have you missed assigning `lRep` value in actual code or the one reproduced here?

Comment: No that didn't work.  The issue is that the dbLookup is not working.  It is producing an error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Toby it's hard to describe the error since I really don't have any debugging informaion with it being server-side javascript.  When I tried to run the code and have it output the value of lRep into a label I got a 'Webiste cannot display this page' error in the web browser.  This is incredibly frustrating.

Comment: To get a more specific error turn on "Display Xpage runtime error page" in Application properties.

Comment: Thanks Toby that worked except it told me what I already knew.  That the DbLookup is not working at all.  I tried to assign the result of the DbLookup to a variable and display it as the value of a label which produced the error.   Because the DbLookup is not working it is producing an error with the variable.

Comment: Create a form or page in regular old Notes in the current database. Set computed text to @DbLookup("Notes":"NoCache"; @Subset(@DbName; 1):"UKCSandbox.nsf";"customerLookup";"P301993";"FirstName");

Comment: David, that does work, however, I need it done on an xPage.  A user needs to provide this information on a webpage based front.

Comment: Please amend your question, not replace you code, the question looses context otherwise.

Comment: Feels like access limitation. Did you test a computed field in a classic Notes form but opened that form in the browser? You could to @ifIserror(result;@text(result);result) to get error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your formatting was lost in copy and paste, your code has flaws. This is not Java, this is JavaScript. Line endings matter and functions don't act on the object, but return a value. Also `@DbLookup` returns a string when [you have exactly one match](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_DbColumn_and_DbLookup), so checking for string doesn't help you.

Your code should look like that:

```
var ukcNumber = Registration.getItemValueString('UKCNumber').toUpperCase();
var resultLabel = getComponent("ukcNumberLabel");
var dbName = @DbName();
dbName[1] = "UKC\\UKCSandbox.nsf";

var lRep = @DbLookup(dbName,"customerLookup",ukcNumber,1);

resultLabel.setValue((lRep) ? "Success" : "Failed");
```

Does that work for you?

**Update**: 2 things to check:

- does the lookup work in the same database using @DbName?
- XPages have the same security constraints as Java agents. Do you have enough rights in the server document to do a 'get value from other database'? Default is No!

Comment: ... and as @Fredrik Norling pointed out: make sure your item has a value before looking

Comment: thanks for the response.  I tried this, but unfortunately the resultLabel keeps outputting "Failed" even if I correctly enter a value that should be found with the dbLookup.

Comment: Then build the code backwards from ground up. Step 1: computed Text with the dblookup fully hardcoded. Step 2: a hardcoded variable Step 3: get the entry from a text box. This will show you what your lookup returns. Then step 4 change to typeof for the result. What do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried making the dblookup work outside of xpages, i.e. with ScanEZ or in the Notes client?

Comment: Could you repost your code? The original one is not going to work, as Naveen and Stefan mentioned. lRep is going to return the value of the lookup, i,e, ukcNumber in the case of success.

Comment: hmmm, tow thoughts: Is the lookup view categorized? if yes, remove the categorization. Second: are you sure your view are 'clean', i.e. is there perhaps another view that has the same name, or alias?

Answer (score 2):

Check your ukcNumber variable so it contains a value.

**Edit**

Check so the user has rights to do the lookup in the other database.
Also try a similar code on an old Notes Form and see if you get the same result.

Comment: I have verified that it does contain a value.  Good suggestion, however.

Comment: I tried to do the lookup using a basic form within the application and the lotus notes formula version of the dbLookup and it returned a result without error.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use keyword '[FAILSILENT]' in your @DBLookup call. It'll return "", if no entry matches with your key. 
If you still have issues, use SSJS/java code to see where it's breaking up.

Comment: I have tried that, but that doesn't solve the issue here.  The issue is that the dbLookup is not working for a value that it should work for.  The same value that works in a regular form using the formula language version of a dbLookup.  I need the dbLookukp to work and return a successful result when it should.

Comment: What's the type of the column you're looking in the view?. Is it Number or Text?

Comment: The column type is 'general'

Comment: Convert the first column to Text, like - @Uppercase(@Text(UKCNumber))

Comment: I tried that, but it still did not work.  I tried doing almost the same dbLookup in an almost identical view as well and that did not work either.  This is an interesting casel.

Comment: Create two databases with some same code that does't work. Zip the databases and place then i.e dropbox or another public sharing way here. And I or someone else will take a look