# XPages @DbLookup returning undefined when looking to another server/database

Tags: xpages

I am trying to perform an @DbLookup to another server/database and continually receive an "undefined" return message.  The database exists, the view name is correct, the key is correct, as well as the column I am trying to return.  I have reader access to the database.

I have tried all these combinations for the server/file path, but none seem to work:

```
var dbName = new Array(session.getServerName(), "my/folder/thisdb.nsf");
var dbName = session.getServerName() + "!!" + my\\folder\\thisdb.nsf;
var dbName = "CN=Server/OU=Name/O=This" + "!!" + my\\folder\\thisdb.nsf;
var dbName = [@DbName([0]), "my/folder/thisdb.nsf"];
```

I have found this post and tried most of the combinations:

http://www.c-lutions.com/c-lutions/mcblog.nsf/dx/08242012095124AMJMMJ69.htm

Are there any other combinations I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16930003/1047998. More specifically this sentence - **XPages have the same security constraints as Java agents. Do you have enough rights in the server document to do a 'get value from other database'? Default is No!**

Comment: My ID is listed in the correct groups on the Security tab of the server document.  Where is the "get value from other database" field on the Server document?

Answer (score 3):

Is your folder's name `my folder` with a space in it? This could be the challenge. I would suggest to ease your pain....
Create one XPage in your target database, have one computed field on it with @DbName() as formula and see what is coming back. Besides that, your formulas have some issues (comments below the entries):

```
var dbName = new Array(session.getServerName(), "my/folder/thisdb.nsf");
```

looks OK unless your folder isn't a subfolder of my. Folders need to be relative to the data directory.

```
var dbName = session.getServerName() + "!!" + my\\folder\\thisdb.nsf;
```

dbName must be an array, this one isn't. Also there are no quotes around the file name

```
var dbName = "CN=Server/OU=Name/O=This" + "!!" + my\\folder\\thisdb.nsf;
```

same here: must be an array, quote is missing. It is confusing since the data source syntax uses the (CN) format of this: `@Name("[CN]";@Subset(@DbName();1)+"!!....`

```
var dbName = [@DbName([0]), "my/folder/thisdb.nsf"];
```

almost there. @DbName() doesn't take a parameter, so you would write:`var dbName = [@DbName()[0], "my/folder/thisdb.nsf"];` or use `var dbName = [@Subset(@DbName(),1), "my/folder/thisdb.nsf"];`

You also can check [great samples](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_DbColumn_and_DbLookup) to play with.

Comment: I apologize about those formulas -- I typed them in incorrectly.  I made a new XPage in the other database and the server came back in canonical format and the file path is correct also.  So I tried this:

Comment: (Hit "Add Comment" to quick -- here is the rest) -- var dbName = [@Subset(@DbName(),1), "myfolder/mydb.nsf"]; -- and it did not work again.  I tried just looking up to the names.nsf and could not get anything to return.var dbName = [@DbName()[0],"names.nsf"]; @DbColumn(dbName, "($People)", 2); --- it just returns "undefined".

Comment: Smells like a rights issue. What's the maximum Internet access of your target nsf? Also: add a classic form with a @DbColumn, what does it show? Then have an agent doing that. You need to be in the server's unrestricted agent field

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the second server is in a trusted server group that is trusted by the first server. For security reasons XPages (and LotusScript) running on any server is unable to access the contents of databases if they are  not in the same trusted server group.